# Integration along the fibres

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'm following Bott's "differential forms in Algebraic topology" and he defines the integration along the fibres of an oriented vector bundle in this way:

Let $E\to M$ be an oriented vector bundle of rank $k$ and $\Omega^*_{cv}(E)$ be the ring of forms whose restriction to the fibres has compact support. For a local trivialization $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$, any such form $\xi$ can be locally spitted in
$$\xi\mid_{\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)}=\pi^*\left(\omega\mid_{\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)}\right)\wedge(pr_\alpha\circ \phi_\alpha)^*\nu=:\omega_\alpha\otimes\nu_\alpha$$
where $\omega\in \Omega^*(M)$, $\nu\in \Omega^*_{c}(\mathbb R^k)$, $\pi:E\to M$ and $pr_\alpha:U_\alpha\times\mathbb R^k\to \mathbb R^k$. Then he defines the integration along the fibers as the morphism $\pi_*:\Omega^*_{cv}(E)\to \Omega^{*-k}(M)$ sending
$$\pi_*(\omega_\alpha\otimes\nu_\alpha)=\omega_\alpha\int_{\pi^{-1}(\cdot)}\nu_\alpha$$
if $\nu_\alpha$ containes a degree $k$ form and $0$ if it doesn't. I want to prove that this local definition extands to a global one.

*my attempt:*

Let $(U_\beta,\phi_\beta)$ be another oriented trivialization. Let $x^\alpha=(x_1^\alpha,...,x_n^\alpha)$ and $x^\beta=(x_1^\beta,...,x_n^\beta)$ be sets of coordinates of $M$ and $t^\alpha=(t_1^\alpha,...,t_k^\alpha)$ and $t^\beta=(t_1^\beta,...,t_k^\beta)$ be the coordinates associated to $\phi_\alpha$ and $\phi_\beta$, respectively. If $\nu_\beta$ is a degree $k$ form, then for $x\in U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$
$$(\pi_*(\omega_\beta\otimes\nu_\beta))_x=\omega_\beta(x)\int_{\mathbb R^k}f^\beta(x^\beta(x),t^\beta)dt^\beta=\omega_\beta(x)\int_{\mathbb R^k}f^\beta(x^\beta(x),g_{\alpha\beta}(x)t^\alpha)\det(g_{\alpha\beta}(x))dt^\alpha$$
then, since we can assume wlog that the structure group of $E$ reduces to $SO(k)$, $\det(g_{\alpha\beta}(x))=1$ and
$$(\pi_*(\omega_\beta\otimes\nu_\beta))_x=\omega_\beta(x)\int_{\mathbb R^k}f^\beta(x^\beta(x),g_{\alpha\beta}(x)t^\alpha)dt^\alpha$$
Now I don't know how $f^\alpha$ and $f^\beta$ are related so I don't know how to keep changing coordinates. Any help?